# how to create a raw file of android gestures

Tags: android, gestures

I have noticed in the android gesture examples, that it reads the gestures from the res/raw folder.  it would be a great thing for my application to include a 'getting started' list of gestures.  that way a user can use the app without having to train it for their own personal gestures.  i would even expect that the majority of users would be happy to use a default set of gestures.

however, i cannot figure out how to generate that initial set of gestures that i would include in the res/raw folder of my application.

anyone have ideas of how to create this file or where to look for more info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Gestures Builder tool](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html).

**UPDATE**: Apparently, that tool no longer exists, sorry.

Comment: I guess that I just need to read 'with comprehension'...

"Every time you add or edit a gesture in the Gestures Builder, a file is generated on the emulator's SD card, /sdcard/gestures. This file contains the description of all the gestures, and you will need to package it inside your application inside the resources directory, in /res/raw."

Answer (score 0):

Download this sample project "Gesture Builder" to create gesture file. This gesture file will be saved to your SD card , copy and paste it to your project's raw folder.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/apps/GestureBuilder/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the playstore link : [Gesture Builder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davemac327.gesture.tool)
You can start building your patterns and a file is saved in SD card with name `gestures`